# how to read excel file using struts2 Application while it converted to .tmp

Tags: file-upload, struts2, jxl, import-from-excel

this is my JSP page... to upload EXCEL file...where I need to uplode 2 different excel file for different action... I hope the tag I is self explanatory...

```
<body>
<s:actionerror />
<s:fielderror />
<s:form action="Admin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="simple">
<big>Import Batch and Tan Details</big>
<br>
<s:file name="uploadToBatch" label="Select a Excel File for Batch import" />
<s:submit action="ImportBatchAndTanDetailsAdmin" value="Import" />
<br>
<big>Allocate Batch</big>
<br>
<s:file name="uploadToAllocate" label="Select a Excel File for Allocation" />
<s:submit action="AllocateAdmin" value="Allocate" onclick=""/>
</s:form>
</body>
```

next is my strut.xml configuration for these 2 actions...

```
<action name="*Admin" method="{1}" class="controller.AdminAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">2572864</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">application/ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</param>
            </interceptor-ref> 
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="error">adminPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">adminPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">adminPage.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

next is the action class...

```
package controller;

import java.io.File;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AdminAction extends ActionSupport {

    private File uploadToBatch;//The actual file
    private File uploadToAllocate;
    private String uploadContentType; //The content type of the file
    private String uploadFileName; //The uploaded file name
    AuthorIndexingDAO DAO = new AuthorIndexingDAO();

    //getters and setters... 
    public File getUploadToBatch() {
        return uploadToBatch;
    }
    public void setUploadToBatch(File uploadToBatch) {
        this.uploadToBatch = uploadToBatch;
    }
    public File getUploadToAllocate() {
        return uploadToAllocate;
    }
    public void setUploadToAllocate(File uploadToAllocate) {
        this.uploadToAllocate = uploadToAllocate;
    }
    public String getUploadContentType() {
        return uploadContentType;
    }
    public void setUploadContentType(String uploadContentType) {
        this.uploadContentType = uploadContentType;
    }
    public String getUploadFileName() {
        return uploadFileName;
    }
    public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
        this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
    }



     //ececute method...


    public String execute (){
         return SUCCESS;
     }


     //other methods....
     public String ImportBatchAndTanDetails(){

         try {

                Workbook w;

                    w = Workbook.getWorkbook(uploadToBatch);
                    Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
                    System.out.println(sheet.getName());


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            addActionError(e.getMessage());

                    return ERROR;

                    }

         return SUCCESS;
     }


public String Allocate(){

         try {

             System.out.println(uploadFileName);
             System.out.println(uploadToAllocate.getName());

                Workbook w;

                    w = Workbook.getWorkbook(uploadToAllocate);
                    Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
                    System.out.println(sheet.getName());


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     return ERROR;

                    }

         return SUCCESS;
     }

}
```

while I import I get this in console...

```
null
upload__6e26fdaa_137cba00800__8000_00000001.tmp
```

and the exception thrown near `w = Workbook.getWorkbook(uploadToAllocate);` was...

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
    at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
    at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
    at controller.AdminAction.Allocate(AdminAction.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:314)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:314)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: I found the reason but not the solution. the reason is that the excel is not created in proper way. It was created just by creating a file with extension `.xls`. But on seeing `MS Excel` can able to open it why dont the java code can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason. The excel which I imported is not created in a proper manner it seems so while I copied the content and pasted it in a new excel and saved it. Later when I import this new excel it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have used jxl api, jxl supports only .xls extension and older, it does not support newer exensions such as .xlsx
  You should have used a incompatible extension most probably .xlsx that's why
'jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream ' exception is thrown.
just try a using a file with .xls extension or instead of using jxl api use poi.